# What to do if favorite open source library does not have a Nuget package

Tags: nuget

If my favorite open source library is not available as a Nuget package on Nuget.org, which of these is preferred?

- Create a Nuget package and use a private Nuget server to host it.
- Create a Nuget package and publish it on Nuget.org - even if I'm not the author.
- Plead with the library authors and ask them to publish it.

Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have some commercial assemblies that we also want to package up and serve using nuget, I opted to create our own private feed.  It is working for us.

I see the value in contacting the library authors and work with them to create a package for the main nuget feed, so maybe when I get more comfortable with creating packages and 'doing it right' I can start doing that for open source libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you have. I solved it by asking whether it would be OK to package the library as a NuGet package and publish it to the official NuGet feed. The authors agreed and I packaged the library. The package has >400 downloads in two months, so there's other people out there using it :-)

So, basically a combination of the second and third option. Most people will agree if you offer to do the work...